# How to open new window after doubleclick so that it becomes active?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm trying to do a seemingly simple thing: after a double-click in one window, I want to open a second top-level (non-modal) window and activate it. However, whatever I do the second window doesn't get activated, the focus remains in the first window.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    height: 480
    width: 640
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked: {
            var w = otherWindowComponent.createObject(root)
            w.show()
            w.requestActivate() // same effect when removed
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: otherWindowComponent
        ApplicationWindow {
            id: child
            width: 400
            height: 300

            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"
                width: 100
                height: 100
                focus: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

UPD: A bit of extra information:

1. I'm on Windows 10 64-bit
2. When I replace onDoubleClicked with onClicked, the window gets activated as expected.

Comment: Have your tried calling [forceActiveFocus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method) on the create window/item? You can do so in `Component.onCompleted`

Comment: I can't call forceActiveFocus on a Window because it requires an Item. Calling it on the embedded blue Rect doesn't help.

Comment: You can try to call `requestActivate()` in `Component.onCompleted`

Comment: @AlexJenter How to verify that the focus has not changed?

Comment: @xeco Unfortunately this doesn't work either :(

Comment: @eyllanesc I see that the system window frame of the second window remains inactive. I have to click inside to activate it. BTW when I replace onDoubleClicked with onClicked everything works as it should!

Comment: @AlexJenter what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: @AlexJenter Try using a Timer and change the focus after 100 ms, maybe keep the focus because you are still pressing the window so for a test it would be interesting to force the focus a few ms later.

Comment: @AlexJenter In Linux it works correctly, I have changed the Rectangle by a TextInput to observe the focus: `TextInput {
                text: "Hello World"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                focus: true
            }`

Comment: @eyllanesc With a timer it works, thanks! Still this seems to be hackish.. I'd like to understand why this happens in the first place. Also when I insert debug output to onActiveChanged in both windows, "active" always is "true"! I don't understand why. Maybe you know? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a Windows bug, in Linux it works correctly. So a workaround would be to set the focus with a Timer a few milliseconds after opening the window.